# Which SwiftUI Widget sizes to use for preview inside app - for iPads?

Tags: ios, swiftui, widgetkit

I need to show Widget preview inside my SwiftUI App.

To get the Widget Sizes for iPhone, I map UIScreen.main.bounds.size to widget sizes specified in Apple Human Interface Guidelines:
https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/components/system-experiences/widgets/#specifications

However it's confusing for iPadOS, because there is this "Target" thing, which is either "Device" or "Canvas". What does this "Target" mean and which one should I use inside my App for the Widget preview size, so that the preview is the same size as the Widget?

[image]

Comment: There is a crude way to find this, add a widget on your iPad, then take a screenshot and measure it in pixels using a ruler app. If you can validate it for one then you can use that to decide for the rest

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I don't have an iPad... I use the simulator, which may show this incorrectly.

Comment: Use the iPad simulator. Ensure you press command 2 to get the pixel accurate simulator

Comment: Based on my measurement it looks like it is the device that matches. Not sure what canvas is